# When will `return !stack.length` ever return `true`?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am confused why this function would ever return `true`. If an item is added to the `stack`, then returning `!stack.length` would return `false`, right? I think I am missing something about how the stack works but I cannot seem to find the answer.

```js
var isValid = function (s) {
  const hash = {
    '(': ')',
    '{': '}',
    '[': ']',
  };

  const stack = [];

  for (const char of s) {
    if (char in hash) stack.push(char);
    else {
      const top = stack.pop();

      if (top === undefined || hash[top] !== char) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  return !stack.length;
};
```

Comment: What is _s_ in the for loop?

Comment: @lukas.j Probably the input string.

Comment: _“If an item is added to the `stack`”_ — Note that items are _also removed_ from the stack using `.pop`.

Comment: Yes, of course. But what is it?

Comment: This looks like the "matched parenthesis" problem that's usually part of programming puzzle collections. The idea for this solution is to track opening elements on the stack. When a closing element is found, the top of the stack is checked and, if matched, removed. At the end of it, the stack should be empty since all elements were matched correctly. Thus the `!stack.length`.

Comment: @lukas.j Yes, that is for the input string. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Ouroborus This was exactly what I was looking for. That made it totally clear, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That will happen when the length of the stack is equal to 0. Putting a `!` in front of `stack.length` will evaluate `NOT 0`. The result of this is `true`.

Take a look at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean). Or to be very specific:

> If the value is omitted or is 0, -0, null, false, NaN, undefined, or the empty string (""), the object has an initial value of false